# Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection..)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, remote-event-receiver, azure-ad, app-web

I have Visual Studio 2019 and i followed the steps mentioned in this link https://www.tatvasoft.com.au/blog/how-to-implement-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-online/ to create a remote event receiver inside our SharePoint online development site.

But when i try to publish the remote event receiver inside visual studio, i got this error:-

> Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line
>   Suppression State Error        Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy
>   experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate
>   the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem
>   persists.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)
>   SharePointAddIn3Web

Here is a screen shot from VS:-

[image]

Here is the diagnostic log error:-

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__213.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

===================
```

Can anyone advice why i am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Having this same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: no..............

Comment: We figured it out on our side. Our corp policy is to proxy all https traffic e because of this the cert presented is the internal proxy cert. To fix it they bypassed the proxy for the deployment site